# Rename file with VBA Name function not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm preparing a code which would every month help users rename specific string in multiple files.

Example: from "Jan" to "Feb", from "Bank" to "Cash", from "Test" to "Sharp" etc. (Bank Statement Jan.xls -> JPM Statement Jan.xls, Form test.xls -> Form sharp.xls, etc.)

I use a function to populate files from all folders and also subfolder picked up a `FileDialog`, then I prompt the user to `InputBox` string to be found and string to be replaced in the file name.

```
Sub testrenametest()

    Dim filedlg As FileDialog 
    Dim xPath As String 
    Dim fileList As Object 
    Dim vFile As Variant 
    Dim FindTerm As String, ReplaceTerm As String, NewFileName As String

    Set filedlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With filedlg
        .Title = "Please select folder"
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
        If .Show <> -1 Then End
        xPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    FindTerm = InputBox("Find string:") ReplaceTerm = InputBox("Replace with:")

    Set fileList = getFileList(xPath)
    For Each vFile In fileList
        If vFile Like "*" & FindTerm & "*" Then
                NewFileName = Replace(vFile, FindTerm, ReplaceTerm)
                Name vFile As NewFileName
        End If
    Next vFile 
End Sub
```

```
Function getFileList(Path As String, Optional FileFilter As String = "*.*", Optional fso As Object, Optional list As Object) As Object

    Dim BaseFolder As Object, oFile As Object

    If fso Is Nothing Then
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    End If

    If Not Right(Path, 1) = "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    If Len(Dir(Path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You need to browse folder first!"
        End
    End If

    Set BaseFolder = fso.GetFolder(Path)
    For Each oFile In BaseFolder.SubFolders
        getFileList oFile.Path, FileFilter, fso, list
    Next

    For Each oFile In BaseFolder.Files
        If oFile.Path Like FileFilter Then list.Add oFile.Path
    Next

    Set getFileList = list
End Function
```

---

It works for some strings like month names but for instance for "test" or "bank" doesn't. It says `Run-time error 53 File not found` on line Name vFile As NewFileName, but the file exists. Sorry for inputting the whole code, but I am unable to pinpoint where might be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem probably lies in the fact that it is attempting to rename a file inside the loop that no longer exists with that name.  Condition the rename  by first double-checking to make sure the file still exists.

```
For Each vFile In fileList
    If vFile Like "*" & FindTerm & "*" Then
            NewFileName = Replace(vFile, FindTerm, ReplaceTerm)
            If Dir$(vFile) <> "" Then
                    Name vFile As NewFileName
             End If
    End If
Next vFile
```

Edit: after additional feedback was provided that the problem is that the replaced string was also found in the path, I suggest the following fix:

```
For Each vFileSpec In fileList
   vPath = Left(vFile, InstrRev(vFileSpec, "\") - 1)
   vFile = Mid(vFileSpec, Len(vPath) + 1)
    If vFile Like "*" & FindTerm & "*" Then
            NewFileName = Replace(vFile, FindTerm, ReplaceTerm)
             Name vFileSpec As vPath + "\" + NewFileName
    End If
Next vFile
```

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't work either. It picks up the files if you list them in immediate window or list them in worksheet, it even change a simple string like "January" to "February", please note, that I am changing always just one string in file name. I have tried to avoid InputBox and put string directly in the code, with no luck. But it doesn't want to replace strings listed above and I would like to know why?

Comment: I have found where the problem is! If the path consists of the finding string, like /test/Bank_test.xlsm, then the error message pops-up. But I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Bill, but I am a bit confused. There are two new variables vPath and vFileSpec, vPath is clear, but the vFileSpec is strange. Could you please have a look? You have loop with vFileSpec and Next vFile.

Comment: vFileSpec is the original full path - drive/folder/filename/extension.  In order to NOT rename the folder name(s) you need to separate the filename and extension from the full file specification, so by getting the position of the last backslash (InstrRev) which I'm fairly sure is a valid VBA function (I use VB 6.0) I can get everything left of that as just the path, and to the right is just the filename.  You can then safely just rename the filename, and re-concatenate the two.